# C++ compiler reordering read and write across thread start

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a piece of multithreaded that I'm not sure is not liable to a data race because of compiler reordering.

Here is a minimal example:

```
int main()
{
  int x = 0;

  x = 5;
  auto t = std::thread([&x]()
  {
    ++x;
  });

  t.join();

  return 0;
}
```

Is the assignment of x = 5 guaranteed to be before the thread start?

Comment: Can you explain in more detail why you think a compiler would launch the thread before the assignment?

Comment: The assignment of `x = 5` is guaranteed to be sequenced before the thread is *created*.

Comment: If anything the compiler may replace this whole thing with int x = 6; return 0; or worse yet, take out everything but the return 0; (When optimized that is)

Comment: @jxh on reading similar code I was struck by the fact that I didn't know how to understand what the compiler or processor could reorder. Obviously the code as written implies a certain sequence but that sequence is not guaranteed by either.

I think that somewhat answers my question though as I guess any such edits generally follow the as-if rule and reordering thread creation with assignment to 5 would change the behavior.

Comment: Yes, the compiler is not to change ordering in a way that violates as-if behavior preservation. However, if the thread was not reading or modifying `x`, the compiler may have optimized `x` away altogether, since there would be no behavior change.

Comment: @jxh, Yes technically the entire operation can be optimized away technically as well, although I'm not sure if this would happen with this code, and likely would be very difficult for a compiler to identify for any non-trivial code. But I will keep in mind next time I create a question on a related topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: The code will work as expected. No reordering will take place

Long answer:

### Compile time reordering

Let's consider what's going on.

1. You put a variable in automatic storage (x)
2. You create an object that holds a reference to this variable (the lambda)
3. You pass that object to an external function (the thread constructor)

The compiler does [*escape analysis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Escape_analysis&oldid=1073607766) during optimization. Due to this sequence of events, the variable x has *escaped* once point 3 is reached. Which means from the compiler's point of view, any external function (except those marked as [pure](https://newbedev.com/attribute-const-vs-attribute-pure-in-gnu-c/)) may read or modify the variable. Therefore its value has to be stored to the stack before each function call and has to be loaded from stack after the function.

You did not make x an atomic variable. So the compiler is free to ignore any potential multithreading effects. Therefore the value may not be reloaded multiple times from memory in between calls to external functions. It may still be reloaded if the compiler decides to not keep the value in a register in between uses.

Let's annotate and expand your source code to show it:

```
int main()
{
  int x = 0;

  x = 5; // stores on stack for use by external function in next line
  auto t = std::thread([&x]() mutable
  {
    ++x;
  });
  int x1 = x; // loads x from stack after thread constructor may (in theory) have modified it
  int x2 = x; // probably no reload because not an atomic variable
  x = 7; // new value stored on stack because join() could access it (in theory)
  t.join();
  int x3 = x; // reload from stack because join() could have changed it
  return 0;
}
```

Again, this has nothing to do with multithreading. Escape analysis and external function calls are sufficient.

Any access from `main()` between thread creation and joining would also be undefined behavior because it would be a data-race on a non-atomic variable. But that's just a side-note.

This takes care of the compiler behavior. But what about the CPU? May it reorder instructions?

### Run time reordering

For this, we can look at the [C++ standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/n4849.pdf) Section 32.4.2.2 [thread.thread.constr] clause 7:

> *Synchronization:* The completion of the invocation of the constructor synchronizes with the beginning of the invocation of the copy of `f`.

The constructor means the thread constructor. `f` is the thread function, meaning the lambda in your case. So this means that any memory effects are synchronized properly.

The `join()` call also synchronizes. Therefore access to x after the join can not suffer from runtime-reordering.

> The completion of the thread represented by *this synchronizes with (6.9.2) the corresponding successful join() return.

### Side note

Unlike suggested in some comments, the compiler will not optimize the thread creation away for two reasons: 1. No compiler is sufficiently magical to figure this out. 2. The thread creation may fail, which is defined behavior. Therefore it has to be included in the runtime.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Regarding run-time reordering, I have a clarification on the synchronization note for 32.4.2.2. I had previously interpreted similar language in the standard to mean that the method does not happen until the thread constructor is completely finished (not during the ctor call). Does it also mean that any instructions before this synchronization point cannot pass over it?

Comment: @MatiasGrioni I'm not enough of a language lawyer to answer with confidence. But the standard is written so that the language doesn't try to stab you in the back. My interpretation of the standard (section 6.9.2) is that every full expression is sequenced in order. And the synchronization establishes an "inter-thread happens-before" relation for these expressions.